# after Enabling Port forwarding in background missing other commands

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes

Simply I have created one Kubernetes service and now I am created a shell script to check the output  of curl. After port-forwarding it is not showing echo commands output. anything missing i is here confused on it.

```
hello_call() {

    if kubectl config get-contexts; then
        echo "Listing ALL available contexts....................."
    else
        echo "Getting contexts failed....."
    fi
    if kubectl config use-context example; then
            echo "Switching to context example"
    else
            echo "Failed to Switch to context example"
    fi

    if kubectl get svc,pods -n hello; then
            echo "Listening all services and pods.........."
    else
            echo "Failed to Listing"
    fi

    echo "#############Checking HTTP service call #####################"
    POD_NAME=$(kubectl --namespace hello get pods -l "app=hello,release=hello" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")

    PORT_FORWARD=$(kubectl --namespace hello port-forward $POD_NAME 8071:8093 >/dev/null 2>&1 &)
    echo "Enabling Port forwarding to execute from local ${PORT_FORWARD}"
    sleep 5

    echo ################# Dev Call ############
    curl http://127.0.0.1:8071/hello -H 'dev: hello'

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `"` in echo command.

```
echo "################# Dev Call ############"
```